# I can't install grub2

Tags: grub2

I can't install grub2 on my system.
i followed the guide, but when i chroot on my ubuntu partition and type:

```
grub-install /dev/sdb
```

I get this error:

> root@ubuntu:/# grub-install /dev/sdb
>   /usr/sbin/grub-setup: error: hd0 appears to contain a iso9660 filesystem which isn't known to reserve space for DOS-style boot.  Installing GRUB there could result in FILESYSTEM DESTRUCTION if valuable data is overwritten by grub-setup (--skip-fs-probe disables this check, use at your own risk).

Here is sudo fdisk -l output:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x6af447e6
Device  Boot       Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048   781459455   390728704    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2       781459456   789272575     3906560   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb3       789272576   976773119    93750272   83  Linux
```

And sudo blkid:

```
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sr0: LABEL="Ubuntu 12.04 LTS i386" TYPE="iso9660"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="08E1AFD109C12FE4" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="1170bc3a-8b75-4c6b-8749-12cecb6db54d" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sdb3: UUID="881202f2-1f9b-4f10-9af5-90424a8dd362" TYPE="ext3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure /dev/sdb is your hard drive? Because usually in the systems that I have seen with Ubuntu till now, sdb refers to the externally connected devices and /dev/sda is your hard drive where you should be installing grub to.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, what is the output of this?

```
mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt
grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sdb
```

Comment: The same: /usr/sbin/grub-setup: error: hd0 appears to contain a iso9660 filesystem which isn't known to reserve space for DOS-style boot.  Installing GRUB there could result in FILESYSTEM DESTRUCTION if valuable data is overwritten by grub-setup (--skip-fs-probe disables this check, use at your own risk).

Comment: This is from a Live CD?

Answer (score -1):

According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158299/why-does-installing-grub2-give-an-iso9660-filesystem-destruction-warning/159775#159775), you need to run

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 seek=1 count=2047
```

to overwrite the master boot record.

Comment: This sounds very destructive given the warning in grub-install's output.

Comment: @pcworld Fwiw, the answer in the linked thread has got six upvotes and accepted status.