# Why does installing Grub2 give an "ISO9660: filesystem destruction..." warning?

Tags: 12.04, grub2

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my computer, but at the end of the installation it gave me an error and it didn't install grub2.
Now I'm trying to install it using the live cd:

This is my sudo fdisk -l:

> Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
> 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
> Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
> I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
> Disk identifier: 0x6af447e6
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>
> /dev/sda1   *        2048   781459455   390728704    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
>
> /dev/sda2       781459456   789272575     3906560   82  Linux swap / Solaris
>
> /dev/sda3       789272576   976773119    93750272   83  Linux

After mounting and chroot the linux partiton, I give grub-install /dev/sda command, and I get:

> /usr/sbin/grub-setup: error: hd0 appears to contain a iso9660 filesystem which isn't known to reserve space for DOS-style boot.  Installing GRUB there could result in FILESYSTEM DESTRUCTION if valuable data is overwritten by grub-setup (--skip-fs-probe disables this check, use at your own risk).

(same error even with grub-install --recheck /dev/sda)

What can I do?
I also tried boot-repair, but I get this error:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/1069353/

Comment: Did you set up the bind mounts before chrooting?

Comment: Yes I did: sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

Comment: You might try erasing the boot track before installing grub: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 seek=1 count=2047`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that you somehow got an iso9660 filesystem header written into your hard disk's boot track.  Since your first partition starts at sector 2048, and you are using the conventional msdos partition table, you can eliminate it by writing zeros to sectors 1-2047 with the following command:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 seek=1 count=2047
```